# Convert Deployment to StatefulSet in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to convert one Deployment to StatefulSet in Kubernetes. Below is my Deployment description .

```
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "4"
  creationTimestamp: "2020-04-02T07:43:32Z"
  generation: 6
  labels:
    run: jbpm-server-full
  name: jbpm-server-full
  namespace: dice-jbpm
  resourceVersion: "2689379"
  selfLink: /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/dice-jbpm/deployments/jbpm-server-full
  uid: 8aff5d46-533a-4178-b9b5-5015ff1cdd5d
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: jbpm-server-full
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        run: jbpm-server-full
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: jboss/jbpm-server-full:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: jbpm-server-full
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /k8sdata/jbpmdata
          name: jbpm-pv-storage
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: jbpm-pv-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: jbpm-pv-claim
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2020-04-02T07:43:32Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2020-04-09T12:35:19Z"
    message: ReplicaSet "jbpm-server-full-b48989789" has successfully progressed.
    reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Progressing
  - lastTransitionTime: "2020-04-09T12:37:05Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2020-04-09T12:37:05Z"
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  observedGeneration: 6
  readyReplicas: 1
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
```

Error:

```
deployments.apps "jbpm-server-full" was not valid:
* : Invalid value: "The edited file failed validation": 

ValidationError(StatefulSet.spec): unknown field "progressDeadlineSeconds" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.StatefulSetSpec, 

ValidationError(StatefulSet.spec): 
unknown field "strategy" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.StatefulSetSpec, 

ValidationError(StatefulSet.spec): missing required field "serviceName" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.StatefulSetSpec, 

ValidationError(StatefulSet.status): unknown field "availableReplicas" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.StatefulSetStatus, 

ValidationError(StatefulSet.status.conditions[0]): unknown field "lastUpdateTime" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.StatefulSetCondition, 

ValidationError(StatefulSet.status.conditions[1]): unknown field "lastUpdateTime" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.StatefulSetCondition]
```

I have attached a persistent volume to this deployment , but i am losing the data whenever the pod is restarted. And now i am trying to convert this existing Deployment Type to statefulSet. I have followed several links , but in vain resulting in errors.

Could you help me.

Comment: what's the error

Answer (score 8):

You have few fields which can't be used in statefulset.

> unknown field "strategy" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.StatefulSetSpec

It should be  [UpdateStrategy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#update-strategies)

> unknown field "progressDeadlineSeconds" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.StatefulSetSpec

As far as I know it's deployment field, it's not available in statefulset.

> ValidationError(StatefulSet.status): unknown field "availableReplicas" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.StatefulSetStatus,

> ValidationError(StatefulSet.status.conditions[0]): unknown field "lastUpdateTime" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.StatefulSetCondition,

> ValidationError(StatefulSet.status.conditions[1): unknown field "lastUpdateTime" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.StatefulSetCondition]

You should delete everything from the [status](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#deployment-status) field. It's created after deployment.

> ValidationError(StatefulSet.spec): missing required field "serviceName" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.StatefulSetSpec

You have to add spec.serviceName with name of your service.

---

It should look like this

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "4"
  labels:
    run: jbpm-server-full
  name: jbpm-server-full
spec:
  replicas: 1
  serviceName: jbpm-server-servicename
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: jbpm-server-full
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: jbpm-server-full
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      containers:
      - name: jbpm-server-full
        image: jboss/jbpm-server-full:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: jbpm-pv-storage
          mountPath: /k8sdata/jbpmdata
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: jbpm-pv-storage
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "my-storage-class"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

---

Links which might be helpful when working with statefulsets.

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/
- https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/statefulset

Comment: Hi Thank you, i will try this and let you know.

Comment: Hi , i got below when i edit my deployment to StatefulSet   -sh-4.2$ kubectl edit deployment.apps/jbpm-server-full -n dice-jbpm
error: deployments.apps "jbpm-server-full" is invalid
A copy of your changes has been stored to "/tmp/kubectl-edit-htuov.yaml"
error: At least one of apiVersion, kind and name was changed

Comment: Can you Please suggest a valid StatefulSet Template so i can put my image and create the container on top it. I tried with the available from kubernetes.io but it didnt worked

Comment: There is a valid template in my answer, but you can't edit your deployment and modify it to statefulset. You should delete the deployment and then create new statefulset.